# Print data based on conditional after filter and mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I try to create tab in React JS. When I return without filter and map, it work well. But when I filter and map before return it, the result doesn't work properly. I don't know this is the right way or not, but I try my best.

So, when I navigate to pending or accept tab, and I don't have data in state, in component TabContent doesn't show 'You dont have any data here'.

And then, in tab pending or accept, when I have more than 1 data, my text in TabContent will looping. I want it doesn't looping, just updating the data length

Here is my code [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-zhukovsky-uygg3l?file=/src/App.js). I hope you guys understand what I mean. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @goooooooo when I don't have data and change to pending or accept tab, in top of tab, the text doesn't appear 'you dont have data'. And when I have data pending or accept, text on the top of tab, will looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution for my question. So in my codesandbox, I try FILTER the items to get true or false the value of property completed. True for accept items, and then false for pending items. And then I MAP the items for get if the items === 0, it will be return "You dont have any items", and then when you have at least 1 item, it will return "You have 1 item".

The solution is, I shouldn't have to MAP the items after Filter. But, I declare a new variable to store value of property completed. Just like this...

```
const pendingItems = items.filter(item => !item.completed);
const acceptItems = items.filter(item => item.completed);
```

And then, in my component do something like this...

```
<>
   //CODE
   {items.length === 0 ? 
      <p>You don't have any items</p> : 
      <p>You have {items.length}</p>
   }
   //CODE

   //CODE
   {pendingItems.length === 0 ? 
      <p>You don't have any items</p> : 
      <p>You have {pendingItems.length} pending item</p>
   }
   //CODE

   //CODE
   {acceptItems.length === 0 ? 
      <p>You don't have any items</p> : 
      <p>You have {acceptItems.length} accept item</p>
   }
   //CODE
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to look at how `map` and `filter` works first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
It says about the passed callback function: `Function that is called for every element...` so basically you do not have any item, it does not call at all

Comment: I just want to show the text in tab content. When I'm in pending tab, and I don't have data in state, it will appear. But when I have data and value of completed === false, it will show the another text. Same as for accept tab too

Comment: what is another text? I can see it does not show any text when the data is empty, and show number of item otherwise

Comment: Just see in TabContent in App.js, there is conditional statement based on property value